# How to define new math delimiters with «»?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to use special math brackets with the symbols «» (french guillemots).
But the problem is that when I define them using `\mbox` or `\text`, they
become italicized with the surrounding text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fopen}{\mathopen\text{\guillemotleft}}
\newcommand{\fclose}{\mathclose\text{\guillemotright}}
\newcommand{\ff}[1]{\fopen #1\fclose}   

\textbf{What I have}

With normal text $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\itshape With text in italic $\ff{O:P:Q}$ } (guillemots in italic)

\textbf{What it should be}

With normal text $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\itshape With text in italic}  $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image: math_guillemots_italic]

Comment: You could replace `\text` with `\textup`…

Comment: It should be `\mathopen{\textnormal{<<}}` (or `\guillemotleft` instead of `<<`).

Comment: …but maybe what you are truly after are `\llangle` and `\rrangle` from the `MnSymbol` package.

Comment: Both `\textup` and `\textnormal` solve the problem. @GustavoMezzetti I'm already using `\llangle` and `\rrangle` for other things.

Comment: @egreg is right, `\textnormal` is (obviously) better, since it will reset *all* font characteristics, and not just the shape, to their “normal” setting.  Of course, with either definition the delimiters you get cannot be used as variable-sized delimiters; but, if you load the `amsmath` package (actually, the `amstext` package would suffice), they will scale down correctly when used in (first or higher order) sub-/superscript.

Comment: I forgot to add, welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font used for `\text` is the one which was in force when the math formula was started, so it will be italic in italic context.

Use `\textnormal`, instead:

```
\newcommand{\fopen}{\mathopen{\textnormal{\guillemotleft}}}
\newcommand{\fclose}{\mathclose{\textnormal{\guillemotright}}}
```

Note also the additional braces; it's only because of the implementation that you don't get an error message. In the example below I also add a way to make the commands respect `\boldmath`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\normalorbold}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\math@version}{bold}=\z@\bfseries\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\fopen}{\mathopen{\textnormal{\normalorbold\guillemotleft}}}
\newcommand{\fclose}{\mathclose{\textnormal{\normalorbold\guillemotright}}}
\newcommand{\ff}[1]{\fopen #1\fclose}   

\begin{document}

\textbf{What I have}

With normal text $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\itshape With text in italic $\ff{O:P:Q}$}

\textbf{What it should be}

With normal text $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\itshape With text in italic}  $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\boldmath $\ff{O:P:Q}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're not short of symbol fonts, you can define one:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{supplsymbols}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{supplsymbols}{bold}{T1}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\fopen}{\mathopen}{supplsymbols}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fclose}{\mathclose}{supplsymbols}{20}
\newcommand{\ff}[1]{\fopen #1\fclose}   

\begin{document}

\textbf{What I have}

With normal text $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\itshape With text in italic $\ff{O:P:Q}$}

\textbf{What it should be}

With normal text $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\itshape With text in italic}  $\ff{O:P:Q}$ 

{\boldmath $\ff{O:P:Q}$}

\end{document}
```